# linux command to transform 'VW_ABCD_EF_GHIJ_KLM_...' into 'AbcdEfGhjKlm...'

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I am trying to modify a string with the pattern 'VW_ABCD_EF_GHIJ_KLM_...' into 'AbcdEfGhjKlm...'

For example "s=VW_ABCD_EF_GHIJ_KLM" must become "AbcdEfGhjKlm".

So far I got `s=VW_ABCD_EF_GHIJ_KLM; echo "${s,,}" | sed -e 's/vw\(.*\)/\1/g'` which produces "_abcd_ef_ghij_klm".

I think I would have to create a variant number of groups for `\(_.*\)` and replace '_[a-z]' for '[A-Z]' in every group, but I could not find how to do it

Comment: Why don't you remove the underscores with `tr -d '_'` command?

Comment: That would do part of the job, but how to change the first letter after the '_' to uppercase?

Comment: I think someone has just cracked this nut : )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on OP's current code to strip the `_` and `U`ppercase the letter following the `_`:

```
$ s='VW_ABCD_EF_GHIJ_KLM'
$ sed -e 's/vw\(.*\)/\1/g;s/_\(.\)/\U\1/g' <<< "${s,,}"
AbcdEfGhijKlm
```

One equivalent while limiting the `VW` removal to the start of the string:

```
$ s='VW_ABCD_EF_GHIJ_KLM'
$ sed -E 's/^vw//g;s/_(.)/\U\1/g' <<< "${s,,}"
AbcdEfGhijKlm
```

**NOTE:** assumes each `_` is followed by a letter (as in OP's example)

Answer (score 2):

A slightly different solution, without the initial `${s,,}` processing:

```bash
$ s='VW_ABCD_EF_GHIJ_KLM'
$ echo "$s" | sed -E 's/^VW//; s/_([^_]+)/\L\u\1/g'
AbcdEfGhijKlm
```

`\L\u\1` will uppercase the first character and remaining are lowercased.

But if the input isn't always uppercase:

```bash
$ s='Vw_ABcd_ef_GHIJ_KLM'
$ echo "$s" | sed -E 's/^vw(.*)/\L\1/I; s/_(.)/\u\1/g'
AbcdEfGhijKlm
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a version that uses `perl` instead of depending on GNU `sed` and it's non-standard `\u`/etc. escapes:

```bash
$ s=VW_ABCD_EF_GHIJ_KLM
$ perl -ne 'my @a = map ucfirst, split(/_/, lc); print @a[1..$#a]' <<<"$s"
AbcdEfGhijKlm
```

Of course, `perl` also supports GNU `sed`-style case-transformation in a regular expression:

```bash
$ perl -pe 's/^VW//; s/_([^_])([^_]*)/\u\1\L\2/g' <<<"$s"
AbcdEfGhijKlm
```

---

Both of these variants, unlike the `GNU sed` ones, do title casing of the letters, not simple upper casing. It's the same thing when it comes to ASCII characters, but if you ever have to expand to alphabets beyond that, it can make a difference.